# xinput not showing driver

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation, touchpad

I am constantly trying to install linux distribution (Ubuntu/mint) alongside Windows 10 on my laptop Acer Nitro 5 AN515-52. But every time , as soon as setup pops up,the touchpad totally stops working, I somewhere read that in some cases, it might be possible that kernels does not support drivers which makes me out of luck.I was somehow able to run 
*xinput* command, but being a novice in linux , I was unable to determine what it conveys. I need to know whether linux can be installed or not.
[[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your touchpad is not being detected. Worst case, you might have to plug in an external mouse for troubleshooting or until the missing driver has been developed and included in the distribution you're using.

From the comments, your hardware model is Acer Nitro 5 AN515-52. By Googling it, I found [this discussion in the Acer support forum.](https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/548336/touchpad-driver-for-acer-nitro-an515-31) In that case, in the BIOS settings, there is a setting for touchpad that can be set to either `Basic` or `Advanced` - if your system has the same thing, try that setting both ways.

Also, it seems that the system discussed in the Acer forum has an I2C-based touchpad. Compared to PS/2 or USB, that's a fairly recent interface for HID devices - the specification was completed in year 2012. In Linux, that should be supported by the `i2c-hid` module, and probably also the appropriate i2c bus driver module. The `i2c-hid` module for Linux was initially developed in late 2012 and it looks like it was added to the main kernel codebase somewhere around kernel version 3.8.

Before the I2C HID specification was in common use, the I2C-related modules could be treated as non-essential in Linux, and that is probably why the installer still does not automatically load them - but if you can complete the installation using an external mouse, the system might well automatically load the necessary modules for I2C touchpad support when booting up to the fully installed Linux operating system.

Comment: I am using Acer  nitro 5 AN515-52....

Comment: I updated my answer based on that information and a bit of Googling.

Comment: Earlier I did changed it to basic, but then whenever I switched to windows, none of the gestures of touchpad worked. It was like going again and again to bios for switching. And I tried external mouse, it was also behaving same way. And as I was able to install linux by keyboard, even afyer doing so as you suggested, it did not loaded necessary models for  I2C